# Trying to pass in variable to the text component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'd like to pass in the stateName variable into the text component. How can I do that when it is inside of the responseJson function?

```
const App = () => {
 fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=ChIJpe7ZFZId9ocRnkR32F9xAcw&key=')
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then((responseJson) => {
 console.log('ADDRESS GEOCODE is BACK! => ' + JSON.stringify(responseJson));
 

const stateName = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter((x: Object) => x.types.filter((t: Object) => t == 'administrative_area_level_1').length > 0)[0].short_name;

return (

<Text>{stateName}</Text> // ???
       
       )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change state when get data, in your situation, you just pass the variable once before get data

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
const App = () => {
 const [data, setData] = useState(null)
 useEffect(() => {
   fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
       const resData = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter((x: Object) => x.types.filter((t: Object) => t == 'administrative_area_level_1').length > 0)[0].short_name;
       setData(resData);
    })
 }, []);



return (

<Text>{String(data)}</Text>

       )

}
```

Comment: Thank you! it works now. One more thing, could you just edit your reply and remove my api key?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are declaring stateName inside last then block try making it global and then update inside then block

Comment: When I added the var stateName; as a global variable outside of the last then block, it passes to the text component. However, It doesn't actually return anything. The actual result should be MN which results in console.log(stateName)